# Fetch the HTML from RTF using Alchemy Plugin

Tags: a4t

Requirement: Webmaster should not have to bother about unnecessary tag when he will paste some text with design in that RTF Design tab if he wants to remove all style then just click on plugin and plugin will remove all tag and style from Design Tab only Plain text remain in that tab.

Resolution:

Created one Alchemy Plugin which will open pop up >>one text box is there >>user will insert their design text >> Click on insert Button >>Pop up will Close >> Plain text will be shown in RTF Design Tab.

Problem:

I need to fetch the RTF field Value in my PopUp Textbox but currently unable to do. Does somebody know the angulia code for fetch from CMS current RTF Field?

The following code is what I did from popup text box. Need to fetch the current RTF Field value.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get the RTF content of a Component from the context menu, you can do something like this:

```
execute: function (selection) {
    if (selection.getCount() == 1) {
        var itemType = $models.getItemType(selection.getItem(0))

        // If the item type is a Component
        if (itemType == "tcm:16") {    
            // Get the selected Component
            var item = $models.getItem(selection.getItem(0))

            // Get the content as string and parse it to get the value of the RTF
            var content = item.getContent()

            console.log(content)
        }
}
```

You can parse the retrieved content to get the required RTF.

[image]

If you are trying to retrieve the RTF from a Component view, you can do something like this:

```
// Get the current view
var view = $display.getView();

// If the current view is that of a Component
if (view && Tridion.OO.implementsInterface(view, "Tridion.Cme.Views.Component")) {   
    // Get the address RTF
    var address = $display.getView().properties.controls.fieldBuilder.getField("address").getValues()[0]
    console.log(address)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am geting below error .Uncaught TypeError: n.getCount is not a function. I have used in Tridion.Controls.RibbonToolbar.
    at f.execute [as _execute] (Component_v8.5.0.22656.180_.aspx?mode=js:1621)

Comment: What is n? Can you log the object n?

Comment: Hi Sabarish, I not added log over there previous n is using as target variable instead on n i am using target variable in function(target){ } from the ribbon toolbar iam unable to achieve your code. your code might be work with context but unable to find the getcount() method ribbon toolbar button event. Please suggest any thing that i am doing wrong in this .